# Simple java regex with groups

Tags: java, regex

I'd like to have regex with three groups - A, B and C, separated by semicolon. Third group should not be mandatory.

I wrote something like that:

```
A=(.*);B=(.*);(C=(.*))?
```

And it works fine, except fact that I always have to put semicolon after B, even if there is no "C" section. And when I write:

```
A=(.*);B=(.*)(;C=(.*))?
```

It's not working. On online regex tester I received such output:

```
1   A=alfa;B=beta;C=gamma
0: [0,21] A=alfa;B=beta;C=gamma
1: [2,6] alfa
2: [9,21] beta;C=gamma
3: [-1,-1] null
4: [-1,-1] null

2   A=alfa;B=beta;
0: [0,14] A=alfa;B=beta;
1: [2,6] alfa
2: [9,14] beta;
3: [-1,-1] null
4: [-1,-1] null

3   A=alfa;B=beta
0: [0,13] A=alfa;B=beta
1: [2,6] alfa
2: [9,13] beta
3: [-1,-1] null
4: [-1,-1] null
```

As you can see on a first example, part with "C=gamma" matches second group, instead of third one. How can I fix that?

Comment: try .*? instead of .* - just a guess thats why this is a comment not an answer

Comment: @AmirAfghani That's not what I'm looking for, please read my question again.

Comment: Are you validating A ( B ( C ) ? ) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out, that a problem was with accepting any sign: `(.*)`. I should have matched anything that is not a semicolon: `([^;]+)`. Final regex looks like:

```
^A=([^;]+);B=([^;]+)(;C=([^;]+))?$
```

Comment: This regex matches `A=,,C=B-A="B=betaChar%^ly;B=A=(C=]{}B`. So, it seems strange to disallow a semi-colon after `A=alpha;B=beta;` Sometimes flexibility needs to be proportional to validation.

Answer (score 0):

```
^A=(\w+);?(?:B=(\w+))?;?(?:C=(\w+))?$
```

Use this.This will give correct groups.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hJ7nT4/7

Comment: @anubhava it does now.

Comment: Hmm now it matches `A=alfa;B=foo;C=bar fff` also.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
A=(.*);B=(.*)(?:$|;C=(.*))
```

**Explanation:**

- Starting the group with `?:` causes it to be "non-capturing" meaning the group won't be remembered for later.  This improves performance and makes things more understandable when it comes to referencing your captured groups (in this case, you can just return $1, $2, and $3 instead of $1, $2, and $4).
- The `$` is an anchor to the end of the string.
- The `|` tells the regex to match either side, so here it will either match the end of the string, or the original C= pattern.

Comment: This still mandates the semi-colon after the `B=something`. OP writes _"I always have to put semicolon after B, even if there is no "C" section."_ and is trying to avoid requiring the final semi-colon.

Comment: But I don't want to include semicolon here. Valid input is either:
"A=alpha;B=beta" or "A=alpha;B=beta;C=gamma"

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work for you:

```
^A=(\w+)(?:;B=(\w+)(?:;C=(\w+))?)?;?$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/pD2tZ0/1)

Answer (score 0):

This might work.

```
 # "A=([^=;\\r\\n]*);?(?:(?<=;)B=([^=;\\r\\n]*);?(?:(?<=;)C=([^=;\\r\\n]*);?)?)?"

 A =                           # Required A
 ( [^=;\r\n]* )                # (1), A Non-delimiter values
 ;?                            # Optional semi-colon
 (?:
      (?<= ; )                      # Must be semi-colon separator behind
      B =                           # Optional B 
      ( [^=;\r\n]* )                # (2), B Non-delimiter values
      ;?                            # Optional semi-colon
      (?:
           (?<= ; )                      # Must be semi-colon separator behind
           C =                           # Optional C
           ( [^=;\r\n]* )                # (3), C Non-delimiter values
           ;?                            # Optional semi-colon
      )?
 )?
```